# Next js 13 Unit test API POST request

Tags: unit-testing, prisma, next.js13

#### Summary

I am writing an API route for newsletter subscription with Next 13 and prisma. I am having trouble mocking the request for the endpoint to write a unit test. I have tried to use node-mock-http but I get error while running the test. In the documentation there is no description how to test endpoints that are not written as handlers.

> "next": "^13.4.2",
> "prisma": "^5.3.1",
> "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",

Below the code of the endpoints I have created

```js
/.route.ts

import prisma from '@/lib/client';
import { response200, response400, response500 } from '@/utils/responses';
import { validateEmail } from '@/utils/validators';

type BodyType = {
    email: string;
};

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    const body: BodyType = await req.json();

    if (!body.email) {
        return response400({ message: 'Email is required' });
    }

    if (!validateEmail(body.email)) {
        return response400({ message: 'Invalid email' });
    }

    try {
        const subscription = await prisma.newsletter.upsert({
            where: {
                email: body.email,
            },
            update: {
                active: true,
            },
            create: {
                email: body.email,
            },
        });

        if (process.env.DEV_ENV == 'production') {
            // TODO send email for activation
            console.log('production');
        } else {
            console.log(
                `http://localhost:3000/api/newsletter/activate/${subscription.id}`,
            );
        }

        return response200({ message: 'subscribed' });
    } catch (error) {
        return response500({
            message: 'Newsletter api is currently broken',
        });
    }
}
```

Below the code for the test I have written

```js
/.test.ts

import { prismaMock } from '@/lib/singleton';
import httpMocks from 'node-mocks-http';
import { POST } from './route';

describe('Newsletter subscription', () => {
    test('Subscribe test', async () => {
        const subscription = {
            id: '5e687d2b-b61f-47ec-959c-753bfdf0e15c',
            email: 'test@email.pl',
            confirmed: false,
            active: true,
            createdAt: new Date(Date.now()),
            updatedAt: new Date(Date.now()),
        };

        prismaMock.newsletter.upsert.mockResolvedValue(subscription);

        const { req, res } = httpMocks.createMocks({
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                email: 'test@email.pl',
            },
        });

        const resp = await POST(req);
        expect(resp.status).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Below the error I get

```
TypeError: req.json is not a function

       8 |
       9 | export async function POST(req: Request) {
    > 10 |     const body: BodyType = await req.json();                                   ^

      at json (app/api/newsletter/sing-up/route.ts:10:38)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/newsletter/sing-up/sign-up.test.ts:27:32)
```

Mocking with node-mocks-http

Answer (score 0):

json should be mocked

```js
import type { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { createRequest, createResponse, RequestMethod } from 'node-mocks-http';
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http';
import { vi } from 'vitest';

export type ApiRequest = NextRequest & ReturnType<typeof createRequest>;
export type APiResponse = NextResponse & ReturnType<typeof createResponse>;

export const mockRequest = ({
  method = 'POST',
  body = {},
}: {
  method?: RequestMethod;
  body?: any;
}) => {
  const { req, res } = createMocks<ApiRequest, APiResponse>({
    method,
    body,
  });

  req.json = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(body);

  return { req, res };
};
```